# Url spam slowdown

Tags: php

I am tryng to make script that when someone spam some url like www.example.com/index.php to slow down him using the sleep function for 30 seconds but it doesnt seems to work...

this is my script so far:

```
<?php

  //   Set Value as ur choice
  $crlf=chr(13).chr(10);
  $itime=1;  // minimum number of seconds between one-visitor visits
  $imaxvisit=2;  // maximum visits in $itime x $imaxvisits seconds
  $ipenalty=($itime * $imaxvisit);  // minutes for waitting


  // Time
  $today = date("Y-m-j,G");
  $min = date("i");
  $sec = date("s");
  $r = substr(date("i"),0,1);
  $m =  substr(date("i"),1,1);
  $minute = 0;


//---------------------- End of Basic Config.  ---------------------------------------  
  //     Get time:
  $oldtime=0;
  //     Update times:
  $time=time();
  if ($oldtime<$time) $oldtime=$time;
  $newtime=$oldtime+$itime;
  //     Bot Detect
  if ($newtime>=$time+$itime*$imaxvisit)
  {
    touch($time+$itime*($imaxvisit-1)+$ipenalty);
   sleep(30);
    exit();
  }

?>
```

Comment: I am not sure what this has to do with JavaScript, CSS, and HTML5.

Comment: You posted this in Javascript, Php, Css, and Html5

Comment: This should be posted in PHP.

Comment: yeah sorry... it was automaticly added by google chrome

Comment: Explain what the script does, and where you got stuck.

Comment: i wanted to make a script that when i refresh some page where the script is included for like 3,4 times to slow down my request using sleep(30); but it doesnt seems to detect when someone is spaming the page.

Comment: 30 seconds? gawd, i close a site if I see my browser going *Lah lah lahhh lah lah* for more than 3 seconds.

Comment: I don't see how you're storing the time values from one visit to another, no use of session or cookie data anywhere.

Comment: it will be only for the people who would want to spam the url so the normal visitors wont be slowed down... thats what i want to make

Comment: Do you at least know what [`touch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.touch.php) does and is used for? *"touch — Sets access and modification time of file"* - So, which file?

Comment: the file where the script will be included as example index.php

Comment: you need to show us how you're using it then.

Comment: You need to do a little research on [Denying DDOS Attacks](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/73369/how-do-major-sites-prevent-ddos)

Comment: 50 scripts sleeping for 30+ seconds is likely to do an much damage as 50+ clients DDOSing you. Think again young man

Comment: *Moving on. Follow me to the coffee shop.... Sam* - @JayBlanchard There are donuts there too!

Comment: *You comin' too Smokey?* @RiggsFolly ^

Comment: *I'll bring the donuts Ralph.* @Fred-ii-

Comment: Oh yeah that's right... they're still warm from what I hear Sam @JayBlanchard

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found a way to make it...

```
<?php

  //   Set Value as ur choice
  $crlf=chr(13).chr(10);
  $itime=1;  // minimum number of seconds between one-visitor visits
  $imaxvisit=3;  // maximum visits in $itime x $imaxvisits seconds
  $ipenalty=($itime * $imaxvisit);  // minutes for waitting

  // Time
  $today = date("Y-m-j,G");
  $min = date("i");
  $sec = date("s");
  $r = substr(date("i"),0,1);
  $m =  substr(date("i"),1,1);
  $minute = 0;


  $ipfile=substr(md5($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]),-3);  
  $oldtime=0;
  if (file_exists($iplogdir.$ipfile)) $oldtime=filemtime($iplogdir.$ipfile);
  //     Update times:
  $time=time();
  if ($oldtime<$time) $oldtime=$time;
  $newtime=$oldtime+$itime;
  //     Bot Detect
  if ($newtime>=$time+$itime*$imaxvisit)
  {
    touch($ipfile,$time+$itime*($imaxvisit-1)+$ipenalty);
    sleep(30);
    exit();
  }
  //     Modifying File Time. 
  touch($ipfile,$newtime);
?>
```

Comment: This is crazy (your concept, your execution, everything).  How can you use the timestamp of one file to control several users ??  As someone already suggested, look at the session variable.

Comment: Not my downvote but seriously; I doubt anyone's going to stick around for no more than 10 seconds if there isn't any indication as to what's going on, or not going on. At the very least, include some JS in there with a *"One moment please..."* or something to that effect. If the problem persists, just log their IP (ok, it's not the best method as those can change or be spoofed) and place it in an array and redirect them to another site or page on yours. Being spammed is a pain in the neck, however you may be doing more harm than good and for legitimate visitors to your site; keep that in mind.